# Wifi list not showing on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, wireless-hotspot

I'm having a problem with my laptop, currently running Windows 8. I used to use Internet with my mobile phone's wifi hotspot and enable laptop's airplane mode when I'm not using the Internet. But, yesterday, when I tried to connect wifi, it showed nothing of any available wifi list. I tried to troubleshoot and it said network cable unplugged. What should I do? Hope you can help me and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to disable the driver of wifi in Device manger and enable it again [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59NQr.png)  i think it would help